# iPhone Calendar List View (Does one exist) (Tapku Fails)

Tags: iphone, list, calendar

I'm after a open source Calendar List View, Tapku has Day and Month, but I need a listView, if it hasn't been done, I have to do it myself, and if so I'll just create a fork of Tapku and add it.

Comment: How did that go? Does Tapku have a list view now? Did you find one in Kal? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya i know one such calendar Kal. you can try Kal. I have given its link below. it has a day view, a month view and a list view of a calendar. try using it. it is the best one.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Are you sure Kal has a list view? I can't find it there in the source.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as the answer as klazuka/Kal clearly does not have a listview