# Want something similar to iPhone Calendar List View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, list, view, calendar

I am trying to replicate the list view in iPhone Calendar. Is there a easy way or a sample code to start off with?

Kindly help. Thanks all for your help..

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111597/iphone-calendar-list-view-does-one-exist-tapku-fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a table view with sections. Use Apple's table view suite sample code project to get some good samples.